# how to finish incomplete master's degree from UCI?

Tags: masters, distance-learning

I am an international student. I almost finished masters in CS @ University of California, Irvine with 2 courses as incomplete. Due to health reasons, I had to drop the school and come back to my home country. Currently my student status is lapsed at University of California, Irvine . is there any way I can finish master degree from an another university??

Comment: Can you perhaps extend what "UCI" is? Most people here will not be aware of any institution with that abbreviation. Also, can't you just declare a "leave of absence" at your institution until you are ready to return?

Comment: Try to contact the university and other universities you want to apply by phone, there is no direct answer.

Comment: @DCTLib I couldn't do it as my student status is lapsed. They asked me to reapply for admission.

Comment: So reapply for admission.

Comment: @tejaswi The thing is that most universities do not give you a Master's degree as their "quality stamp" unless you studied a substantial amount of time at their institution. You should be able to find a university that will give you credit for some of the courses that you already did in Irvine, but depending on the officer in charge probably not all of them. In addition to reapplying for admission at Irvine, I'd suggest to contact a few other universities that you may be interested in as well.